# $a_n>0$ and $(a_n)$ is decreasing. Suppose that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_{2n}}$ converges. Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n}$ also converges.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n}$ be a series such that for each $n$, $a_n>0$ and $(a_n)$ is decreasing. Suppose that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_{2n}}$ converges. Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n}$ also converges. I try to prove by using definition but I got nowhere . Can anyone guide me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will show that the sequence $b_k=\sum_{i=1}^{k} a_i$ is bounded .

As $\sum_{i=1}^{k} a_{2i}$ is convergent so it is bounded and let $\sum_{i=1}^{k} a_{2i}<M,\forall k\in \mathbb{N}$

$b_{2k}=\sum_{i=1}^{2k} a_i=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} a_{2i+1}+\sum_{i=1}^{k} a_{2i}<a_1+\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} a_{2i}+\sum_{i=1}^{k} a_{2i}<a_1+2\sum_{i=1}^{k} a_{2i}<a_1+2M$
(Similarly for odd index)

So we have the sequence $b_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i$ is bounded and as it is monotonically increasing (as $a_i>0$) so it is convergent.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\displaystyle A_n=\sum_{k=1}^n a_{2k}$  and $\displaystyle B_n=\sum_{k=1}^n a_{2k+1}$. Since $a_k>0$, the sequences $(A_n)$ and $(B_n) $ are increasing, we have

$$B_n\leq A_n\leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{2k},$$
so $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{2k+1} $ exists and $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{k}= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{2k}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{2k+1}$ exists as well.