# If $\sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ diverges, then does $\sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty a_{2n}$ diverge too?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Assume $a_n \geq 0$ and a decreasing sequence and $\lim a_n = 0$

The examples I have in mind are $\sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ and $\sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty \log \left ( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right ) $ both diverge. But what if we extract a subsequence of even numbered indices.

What about for a general subsequence?

Comment: $1+0+1+0+1+0+\cdots$.

Comment: okay, if we have a decreasing sequence and $\lim a_n = 0$?

Comment: Then $a_{2n}\ge\frac12(a_{2n}+a_{2n+1})$.

Comment: If $(a_n)$ is decreasing, then $$\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_{2n}\geq\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=2}^{2N+1} a_k.$$ Now the assumption tells that this lower bound diverges to $+\infty$ as $N\to\infty$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$a_n>0$ and $(a_n)$ is decreasing. Suppose that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_{2n}}$ converges. Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n}$ also converges.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/313974/a-n0-and-a-n-is-decreasing-suppose-that-sum-n-1-inftya-2n-co)

Comment: ... the case for a "general subsequence"? It that entertained by the other question also?